# Auditing / searching private Github repositories for specific code

Tags: github

Google Maps v2 is being retired, so I need to audit all our private repositories on Github for uses of it. I could clone them all down and run a `grep`, but there are a lot (mid 3 figures) so I’d rather do everything on the server if possible. Unfortunately Github’s search will only search public projects (as far as I can see), and I can’t see anything in the API to do what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there *already is* a feature to `grep` code from private GitHub repos:

[image: screenshot]

However, it has no API, so you'd need to do some good old scraping of links with the format:

https://github.com/creaktive/WUB/search?q=BEGIN&choice=code&l=&start=

To walk multiple repos, you could use iMacros for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp)/[Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/), [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) if you're up to some Perl-fu, or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) if you're a JavaScript ninja.

Comment: I’d shamefully missed this; this is probably the best solution in the absence of any official API to do it. Bounty to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you know you're looking for patterns that are more or less consistent you can use the Github API to grep only the files that might be of interest to you.

For instance,  you can get the contents of a file via the API:  http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents

However, this assumes you know what files you've got (works well for Gemfile in Ruby, or requirements.txt in Python, not so great for Javascript).

The other option is to automate the search of the repos locally.  It would be perfectly possible to write a script to git clone each repo in turn, grep it, and output the results (assuming you've got the time required for this to run, and the disk space).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a previous use of [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) and typically has usecases such as yours.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at this (I hadn’t seen it before) but it’d require me to have a full set of repos on my local machine: something I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Ideally, you'd want to do it locally, but handling changes in source code + compiling + building on the server is going to cost you more.

Comment: I’ll need to edit any repos that contain code I need to adjust, yes. But this will probably be <10% of the available repositories, and I don’t want to have to pull them all down to audit them.